# Convert numpy array to panda dataframe, dtypes lost

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a numpy array structured as follows (actual data has more cols though!)

```
data = np.array([[ 2000,"working"], [800 ,"not working"], [3000,"working"]])
```

I convert this into a panda DataFrame as follows:

```
df_data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

However, when converting this, the `int` dtypes are converted to `object` dtypes

```
df_data.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 2 columns):
0    3 non-null object
1    3 non-null object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 128.0+ bytes
```

**However, I want to keep the int values.**

Not sure why it does that?

Comment: np.array only keep one type , so it will convert to object

Comment: But the actual data has 14 columns. Would be not very good code if I had to hard code those columns back to int

Comment: `df.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='ignore')`

Comment: I have mark the duplicate , since it is very similar with date parse

Comment: Thanks WeNYoBen!

Comment: Look at the `dtype` of `data`.  It probably a string, not a mix of strings and numbers.  Pandas uses object dtype in place of numpy strings.  What if you created `data` as object dtype?

Comment: Yes. Thanks, it was a list within a np.array and the list  had as dtype object